# Split string values and assign them to variables in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, split

I want to get color values from a string and assign them like

```
  n1=red
  n2=blue
  n3=orange
  And so on....
```

Sample code is given below. I don't want to write these, just assign values to n.

```
   strArray = Split(red, blue, orange, blue)
   Dim i
   For i = 0 to Ubound(strArray)
   response.write strArray(i) & "<br>"
   Next
```

Comment: "I want to get color values from a string" -- what does the string look like? Also, the use of variables with names like `n1,n2,n3` suggests that you should use a single variable which holds an array or dictionary rather than a bunch of separate variables.

Comment: String is with color as already given 
strArray = Split(red, blue, orange, blue)

I want to use n1, n2, n3 in some other sql query as given below:

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to pass 4 arguments to `Split`. Do you mean `Split("red, blue, orange, blue", ",")`?

Comment: This is just example, numbers may vary 4, 5, 6. I want to use then to sql like

SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
column LIKE '%n1%' OR 
column LIKE '%n2%' OR 
column LIKE '%n3%' OR 
column LIKE '%n4%' OR

Comment: @Babar in which case your whole approach is wrong, dynamically setting variables in VBScript doesn't mean they can then be magically used in a SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2(v=vs.84).aspx):

```
strArray = Split("red, blue, orange, blue",",")
For i = 0 to Ubound(strArray)
  Execute("n" & (i+1) & " = Trim(strArray(" & i & "))")
Next
```

Then you will have 4 variables `n1,n2,n3,n4` whose values are the successive colors, as the following test shows:

```
msgbox n1
msgbox n2
msgbox n3
msgbox n4
```

Warning: never use `Execute` on a string which an untrusted user has supplied.

Comment: How to do that, i don't see any option here.

Comment: There is one problem with sql statement. If there are values of n1,n2,n3,n4 available then sql statement works. But if there are two or three n values, then the LIKE does not find anything. How to match Like values with number of n values in this sql statement.

Comment: @Babar the hollowed out tick symbol below the answer votes is how you accept an answer, doing so will turn the tick symbol green. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/202529).

Comment: @Babar there is no mention of a SQL statement in your original question, please don't tack extra queries on to already answered questions. Instead, go and ask another question providing a [mcve].

Comment: @Babar As others have said, you would need to ask a separate question. My knowledge of SQL isn't very deep, but if you ask a question on the SQL tag there would be a better chance of getting a good answer. As far as the mechanics of accepting an answer, there should be a check mark next to the answer to accept it if you want.

Comment: I have accepted the answer. posted another VBscript question here. You might have an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486950/pre-populate-checkbox-in-a-loop-vbscript

Comment: @Babar I don't really have time right now and it looks like you already have an answer. It is a well-written question which I upvoted.