# pre-populate checkbox in a loop

Tags: loops, checkbox, vbscript

I am trying to pre-populate the checkboxes in a `Do..Loop`. The values from the `QueryString` are matched with the value from database. But in this case, all check boxes are checked irrespective of any `QueryString` value.

The VBscript code is given below:

```
<%
Do While Not RS.EOF
    Designchk = Request.QueryString("Designer")
    Designchk2 = RS("Brand")

    If InStr(Designchk, DesignchkP2) Then
        chkd = "checked" 
    End If

    ListL = ListL & vbCrLf & "<li><label class='contR'>" & Designchk2 & _
            "<input type='checkbox' " & chkd & " name='Designer' value=" & _
            Designchk2 & "></label></li>"
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
%>
```

Comment: BTW, I'd recommend using `Do Until` instead of `Do While Not`. The semantic is the same, but the former is easier to understand for human readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never reset `chkd` anywhere, so once checked it remains that way.

Change this:

```
If InStr(Designchk, DesignchkP2) Then
    chkd = "checked" 
End If
```

into this:

```
chkd = ""
If InStr(Designchk, DesignchkP2) Then
    chkd = "checked" 
End If
```

and the problem will disappear.